# Get buttons to go on the same line

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I am trying to get the following buttons on the same line and be centered, but everything I tried will either pull them to the left and wont keep them centered.

```
<DIV align=center>
<A id=enquire title="Enquire" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages /Enquire.aspx target=""></A> 
<A id=join title="Join" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages/Join.aspx target=""></A> 
<A id=useandhelp title="Use and Help" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages/UseandHelp.aspx target=""></A> 
<A id=change title="Change" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages/Change.aspx target=""></A>
<A id=leave title="Leave" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages/Leave.aspx target=""></A>
</DIV>
```

Can anyone help?

Cheers!

Comment: try to Surround center with "" <DIV align="center">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to Surround center with "" `<DIV align="center">`

if it still not working add the following style to your page or CSS file

```
<style>

  .divcenter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center 
}    
< /style>
```

**the final code should be**

```
<DIV class="divcenter">
<A id=enquire title="Enquire" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages /Enquire.aspx target=""></A> 
<A id=join title="Join" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages/Join.aspx target=""></A> 
<A id=useandhelp title="Use and Help" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages/UseandHelp.aspx target=""></A> 
<A id=change title="Change" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages/Change.aspx target=""></A>
<A id=leave title="Leave" href=/testsite/knowledegbase/TestMG2/Pages/Leave.aspx target=""></A>
</DIV>
```

You can also use this [link](http://howtocenterincss.com/#contentType=div&horizontal=center&vertical=top) to generate your appropraute CSS

Comment: Perfect, adding the CSS and adding the class fixed it. Many Thanks